# Is it possible to use cloud functions background triggers and express app in two separate files?

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I once did a project in which I had Cloud Functions background triggers and all of my express app routing functionality in a  single file and boy, did it become huge.

I would like to know if it's possible to separate then, and in a single `firebase deploy` command, send both files to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  [Use require() to pull in modules](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp) from other JavaScript files you create.  Or, if you're using TypeScript, [create modules and `import` them](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

You have a lot of flexibility on how you can achieve your goal.  There is not just one right way to modularize your code.